# How to pass subobject into function and check its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

With regular object I would do

```
var obj = {"property_1" : "red"}, {"property_2" : "green"};

$.each(obj, function(key, value){}
   if(value == 'red'){ //Do something }

);
```

How pass and check value if I have object inside object:

```
var obj = {"property_1" : {"color" : "red"}, {"property_2" : {"color" : "green"}};
```

Comment: That first example is not doing what you think. You want a collection. That won't work, is not correct syntax. See here http://jsbin.com/noqob/1/edit

Comment: @elclanrs He's not using `$.fn.each`. `$.each` is a different function.

Comment: @sabof: I mean a JavaScript collection: `[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}...]`

Comment: @elclanrs You mean Array? `$.each` works with either. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: I mean collection, array of objects. This would be the right data structure for this case IMO: `var properties = [{color: 'red'},{color: 'green'}]`. The index is the property number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this. I've also cleaned up the syntax.

```
var obj = {"property_1" : {"color" : "red"}, "property_2" : {"color" : "green"}};

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
   if (value.color == 'red') {
     console.log('found');
   }
});
```

Comment: thx sabof, that's it. I went with same logic but I must have had syntax errors.